# Namespace in luatex

Tags: luatex, tex-core

Is it possible from luatex access registers where all names of command sequences are stored. Is it possible to pull out this list of names? I am looking for a way to trace how namespace changes during compilation of latex document.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a dump of the hashtable that stores the command names.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\wibble{hello}

\begin{document}

\directlua{
for i, v in pairs (tex.hashtokens())
do
texio.write_nl(i)
end}
\end{document}
```

it outputs a long list, but testing with

```
lualatex testfile.tex | grep wibble
```

produces

```
wibble
```

Showing it includes all commands defined up to the point of the dump.

the luatex manual warns that this is the internal hashtable, not all the commands may be defined or reachable from tex due to scoping and other issues.